# Is there a conventional term for the "pullback cube"?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$

In a word, is there a name for the limit of
$\begin{CD}
@. A \\
@.@VVV
\\
B @>>> X \\
@. @AAA \\
@. C
\end{CD} \> ? $

In many words: This can be expressed as a cube, any pullback-shaped subgraph of which is indeed a pullback. Here I found it referred to as "pullback cube" and "pullback of a pullback diagram". However, "pullback cube" query in google leads either back here on mathexchange, or to articles about cubes from homotopy theory, which are not the same. It strikes me as strange that I never saw such limits studied on their own or at least having a name.

For instance, if $A, B, X$ are schemes and you are interested in $A \times_X B \to B$, it's often useful to take at first an affine subscheme $C \hookrightarrow X$ and pull it along $A \to X.$ Each time I do that I feel that I invent the wheel.

A different example: $\text{hofib}(X \to Y) = \{*\} \times_Y Y^I \times_Y X,$ which is a pullback cube of $\{*\} \times Y, Y^I, Y \times X$ over $Y \times Y.$

Is there any literature where this construction is abstracted and seriously discussed?

Comment: Perhaps this is a place where the "fibre product" terminology is a bit more relaxed? I always think of pullback _squares_, but I'm happy to take the fibre product of $> 2$ objects (over $A$).

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Good point, but do people really speak this way?

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but I talk about fibre products all the time.

Comment: all the time? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the special case of a [wide pullback](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/wide+pullback). It is also just a 3-fold product in the slice category $\mathcal{C}/X$.